# Google Analytics only showing a fraction of unique hits

Tags: analytics, server

My web server is showing 5 times more unique hits than the google analytics dashboard, i'm afraid when I add the ads in my website it won't show the real amount of views/clicks etc, is there any way to debug this? I've checked and the pages i'm hosting have the correct tracking code.

Web server analysis
[image]

Analytics report for the same day

[image: http://i.imgur.com/tyMb69R.png]

Considering that there is things like Adblock, Ghostery, referral spam, non javascript enabled browsers and people that opt out of google tracking, that could amount up to 100-250 unique ips/day, or 1/10 ~ 2/10 of the traffic, but not 4/5.

Comment: By accessing the raw access log, your "web server" would seem to be including spiders and other non-JS (real?) users. Whereas GA most probably excludes this traffic (it requires JS to function after all).

Comment: Yes, although that wouldnt account for 1000 unique ips, maybe 100, at most.

Comment: Your users are probably blocking Analytics. http://kennystechtalk.blogspot.com/2016/03/adblockanalytics.html